# method in class cannot be applied to given types. Can you see what I have to change?

Tags: javascript, java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocBzp.png)

and

this is all of my code formats. Can you see what I have to change?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Human
{
    private int xPos;  // x-position of the ball
    private int yPos;  // y-position of the ball
    private int size;  // size of the ball

public Human(int size)
{
    this.size = size;
}

public void setPos(int x, int y)
{
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
}

public void show()
{
    Canvas cv = Canvas.getCanvas();
    cv.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, size);
}

public void moveRandom()
{
    Canvas cv = Canvas.getCanvas();
    int cvWidth = cv.getWidth();
    int cvHeight = cv.getHeight();

    Random r = new Random();
    int x, y;

    while (true)
    {
        x = r.nextInt(cvWidth);   // 0..cvWidth-1
        y = r.nextInt(cvHeight);  // 0..cvHeight-1
        setPos(x, y);

        cv.clear();
        show();
        pause(50);
    }
}

private void pause(long timeMillis)
{
    long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeStart + timeMillis)
        ;
}
```

}

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

So, the error message in your screenshot says

> method drawCircle in class cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: int, int, java.lang.String, int
>
> found: int, int, int

You are trying to call the method with three integers `cv.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, size);, whereas you need to input int, int, String and int. Maybe changing the variable size to type String helps.